# android studio NDK compile with third library(.so)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm using android studio ndk. I want to make a .so of JNI, but this .so refer to the other .so,  so I should link to the other .so when compile the JNI .so
the following is my JNITest\app\build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.administrator.jnitest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            moduleName "JniTest"
            ldLibs "log", "z", "m" ,"netsdk", "rtspclient" , "osl"
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

"netsdk", "rtspclient" , "osl" is the dependency shared library, I don't know how to add the .so path to them and ndk report many unreference now

Answer (score 0):

The gradle DSL supports **ldFlags**, e.g.

```
ldFlags += "-L<path-to-libs>"
```

Also, you should instruct Android Studio to pack the 3rd party libs into the APK:

```
jniLibs.srcDirs = "<path-to-libs>"
```

Comment: the gradle report Error:(16, 0) Could not find property 'ldFlags' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions_Decorated@15066cb9.

Comment: I'm using AS 1.2.1.1 version

Comment: Sorry, in your version you should drop **`=`** and **`+=`**

Comment: the same result  as above,I will try 1.4 version later